# Why parameter decorator doesn't work (call) in Services?

Tags: service, nestjs, decorator

I've just defined a simple param-decorator to use in my service (as a parameter decorator), but the decorator is not called.

```js
// my-param.decorator.ts
export function MyParamDecorator(
  target: object,
  propertyKey: string,
  parameterIndex: number,
) {
  console.log('Hello from decorator!');
}
```

```js
// my-service.ts
...
  async serviceMethod(@MyParamDecorator query) {
    console.log('Hello from MyService');
    return true;
  }
...
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Can you provide all of the startup logs as well? I'd be very surprised if the decorator doesn't work at all

Comment: @JayMcDoniel Thanks Jay for response. There is not any clue (errors or something else) in the startup log. What do you looking for in logs? Notice that it only happens in Service layer, but in controller everything is fine.

Comment: Decorators run on file import, so the `console.log('Hello from decorator!')` would be one of the first logged lines in the log. Nest doesn't modify how decorators behave, so it should be there.

Comment: UPDATE: it is not call also in the controller! but other nest parameter-decorators such as `@Body` `@Query` are called from controller!

Comment: I didn't know it. I thought it would be call after the method call! Yes the log is here. so, everything is fine?!

Comment: @JayMcDoniel Actually, I want to call this decorator after each method call with new argument passed to it! is that this way correct I choose?

Comment: For that, you'll need to modify `descriptor.value` [similarly to how the example in the Typescriptdocs does](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#parameter-decorators)